# Laravel 5: Connect 3 tables with 2 pivot tables

Tags: pivot-table, laravel-5

I'm trying to find all rows in **c** table *(see DB schema)* associated with one row in **a** table. Connected by 2 pivot tables each with **n:m** relationship.

DB Schema: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6HbB.png

Here is how I defined the relationships:

```
In model A: 
  $this->belongsToMany("App\B");

In Model B:
  $this->belongsToMany("App\A");
  $this->belongsToMany("App\C");

In model C:
  $this->belongsToMany("App\B");
```

I've already reached the goal by addding the method **getC** into **A** *Eloquent model*:

```
public function getC() {
    $cCollection = new Collection();

    $this->b()->get()->each(function($b) use (&$cCollection){
        $b->c()->get()->each(function($c) use (&$cCollection) {
            $cCollection->add($c);
        });
    });

    return $cCollection;
}
```

And it works perfectly, but it doesn't fit my requirements. If i build a new collection i'm unable to do pagination, etc... on rows from **C** table. It would be also pretty heavy in case of thousand of rows.

If i try to do something like this:

```
A::findOrFail($id)->b
```

i get a Collection of **B** but i'm unable to directly get all **C**. If i iterate the collection of **B**:

```
A::findOrFail($id)->b->each(function($b){
    $b->c();
});
```

I get all **C** but I lose direct access to **C** Eloquent and i'm unable to do count, paginate, etc.. on it.

Is there any other way how to do something like this?

```
A::findOrFail($id)->b->c->paginate(n);
A::findOrFail($id)->b->c->count();
A::findOrFail($id)->b->c->all();
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference - The same question was also put by its author on [LARAVEL.IO](https://laravel.io/forum/connect-3-tables-with-2-pivot-tables) where he accepted an answer.

---

Excerpt:

What you need is a "has many through many" relationship but laravel doesn't support it.

Here is an old thread about it: [hasManyThrough with Many-To-Many](http://laravel.io/forum/03-04-2014-hasmanythrough-with-many-to-many).

There are some workarounds people have come up with and I can offer you another one which I think is pretty clean. It's a scope that has nested whereHas inside the model C

model C --

```
public function scopeHasAViaB($query, $ids) {
    if (empty($ids)) {
        return new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();
    }
    return $query->whereHas('b', function ($query) use ($ids) {
            $query->whereHas('a', function ($query) use ($ids) {
                $query->whereIn('id', $ids);
            });
        });
}
```

-- controller code --

```
$modelAkeys = [1,2];
$cc = ModelC::HasAViaB($modelAKeys)->paginate(10);
```